# Use Feature Constructor in Orange to extract number from string?

Tags: orange

I would like to use [the Feature Constructor](https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/visual-programming/widgets/data/featureconstructor.html) to extract numbers from a column of strings.

```
 Input          Output
S.c 3224   ---> 3224
South      ---> 0
322523     ---> 322523
S-1c 4     ---> 14
-1.37      ---> 137
```

Internal Orange 3.7.0 Documentation says *For continuous variables you only have to construct an expression in Python.*  Great!

I found information about allowed functions in [the feature constructor code](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/blob/master/Orange/widgets/data/owfeatureconstructor.py):

```
#Only expressions with no list,set,dict,generator comprehensions
#are accepted.
<...>
__ALLOWED = [
    "Ellipsis", "False", "None", "True", "abs", "all", "any", "acsii",
    "bin", "bool", "bytearray", "bytes", "chr", "complex", "dict",
    "divmod", "enumerate", "filter", "float", "format", "frozenset",
    "getattr", "hasattr", "hash", "hex", "id", "int", "iter", "len",
    "list", "map", "memoryview", "next", "object",
    "oct", "ord", "pow", "range", "repr", "reversed", "round",
    "set", "slice", "sorted", "str", "tuple", "type",
    "zip"
]
```

Based on the list, I was hoping to use an expression like this:
`int(filter(str.isdigit, inputStringColumn) or 0)`

...but that is an "Invalid Expression" (no further feedback)

How can I extract a number from a string?

Comment: How about `int(inputStringColumn) if inputStringColumn.isdigit() else 0` ?

Comment: @StephenRauch `"Attribute Error: 'Value' object has no attribute 'isdigit'"`

Comment: @StephenRauch Part of the trouble - I thought the column was a string because it has letters, but it isn't.  If I first cast to string, then your solution at least runs .  `int(str(inputStringColumn)) if str(inputStringColumn).isdigit() else 0`  It doesn't work completely, however - when the whole field is digits, it returns those digits.  Otherwise it returns 0  (it isn't going piecewise through.)

Comment: With help from the error message generated by Stephen Rauch's suggestion, I worked out one way to do this: `int( ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, "0"+str(inputColumn) ) ))`  I will write this up as an answer later, unless someone comes along with something better.

Comment: It would be much nicer if `re` (regex) module were exposed. While writing up the answer, also consider opening a bug/enhancement report. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to highlight [Adam](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/41478/adam)'s timesaving answer

```
int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, "0"+str(inputColumn))))
```

[image]